# Windows 8 apps - EntranceThemeTransition using C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition.aspx
I finally learned how to enable that entrance transition to my stack panel using these lines of code inside my StackPanel codes in XAML

```
      <StackPanel.Transitions>
          <TransitionCollection>
              <EntranceThemeTransition/>
          </TransitionCollection>
      </StackPanel.Transitions>
```

it works, but can we do this in C# codes? I want to enable it when I click a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
myStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions = new 
             TransitionCollection {new EntranceThemeTransition()};
```

Comment: I put it in my private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {}. cause me an error

Comment: Mayank is not a psychic. You need to provide specific details of what the error is.

Comment: ;) lol, yeah please provide some more details so I can enjoy answering your question.

Comment: my bad.. here's the error: 
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: where are you getting that error? Edit your post and add some code so I have a clear picture.

Comment: hello, it successfully added the animation, but I wanted to replay the animation as the button clicked too, is there any way to do it? thanks

Comment: not sure how to do that. Please create another question for that so someone else can answer.